# Defining keyboard shortcuts from an argument in a function

Tags: key-bindings, string

I would like to write a command that defines key bindings for me, so that I can feed in key `y` (for example) and have it define key bindings for `M-y`, `C-y` etc.

I'm trying to `concat` the command argument into a string, but it gives me the error `Invalid modifier in string`.

```lisp
(defun my/keypress-definer (keypress)
  (interactive)
     (concat "\C-" keypress))

(my/keypress-definer "a")
```

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `concat` function takes a list of SEQs and returns a string.

To get the string that describes your key sequence, you would simply write

```el
(concat "C-" keypress)
```

Use the `kbd` function to return the actual key representation.  I think you may end up with something like the following

```el
(defun my/keypress-definer (keypress)
  (define-key my-key-map
    (kbd (concat "C-" keypress)) 'my/ctl-function)
  (define-key my-key-map
    (kbd (concat "M-" keypress)) 'my/meta-function))

Documentation:

 - [Creating Strings][1]
 - [Key Sequences][2]

  [1]: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Creating-Strings.html
  [2]: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Key-Sequences.html
```

Comment: It works, it works, it works, it works! You are the absolutely best type of person, thank you. :)

Comment: ok - I'm not going to stop answering questions.  You made my day!